# How to upload a file from an html into Django forms

Tags: html, django

Everytime I upload a file, `forms.is_valid()` = False.

below is my views.py:

```
def upload_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():  # this is always FALSE!!!
            
            # write file into folder first
            text = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            print("text")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('pdfExtractor_app/result.html')
    else:
        print("form not valid")
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'pdfExtractor_app/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Here is my upload.html file:

```
<body>  
<form method="POST" class="post-form">  
        {% csrf_token %}  
        {{ form.as_p }}  
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>  
</form>  
</body>
```

I input a title and a file,
but I get the form never gets read in views.py.

This is what's I get form.errors

```
 <ul class="errorlist"><li>file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>        
[15/Dec/2021 21:10:56] "POST /upload_pdf/ HTTP/1.1"
```

This is what's in the Querydict:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['b123ASDDoddfkkdzrPXa5P2kKEsp7dBASXQWXfffwwdffgKGLGVVffML'], 'title': ['as'], 'file': ['UsabilityTest.pdf']}>
```

Thank you!

Comment: where you get ``<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['b123ASDDoddfkkdzrPXa5P2kKEsp7dBASXQWXfffwwdffgKGLGVVffML'], 'title': ['as'], 'file': ['UsabilityTest.pdf']}>`` in form valid block or in form invalid ?

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag in your template

Comment: what is your `handle_uploaded_file` function?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag in the template did the trick and made the `form.is_valid()` equal true.

I changed the uploads.html to:

```
<body>  
<form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        {% csrf_token %}  
        {{ form.as_p }}  
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>  
</form>
```

Thanks everyone for the helpful feedback in the comments!